# Sitecore and HTML files

Tags: html, sitecore, media, sitecore-media-library

We have a bunch of files (css, js, html, flash, swf, etc) put together by a third party to show videos on our site. This link is an example of the type of rendered output that i'm talking about - http://www.esi-intl.com/public/us/resources/virtualclassroom/presentation.htm. This isn't my company but I was able to find this via google since our site is not live yet.

Our editors would like to include these files in the Media Library and display these pages from there. I've tried to include these files but the HTML page doesn't render instead it is offered as a download. I've tried commenting out the Mime type in the Mimetype config file but I'm not having any luck.

Can the Sitecore media handler be modified to get these HTML files to render as pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html in media libary could.

To get the correct mime-type look at the setting `name="Media.RequestExtension"` set the value to `""`  then you get the original extension.

That makes things become easier for the web server to give the correct mime type.

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver. Setting that property to empty and adding this to html mime type in mimetypes.config -  <forceDownload>false</forceDownload> - fixed it.